# Google Sheets API Python set specific color values for 2 value doughnut chart

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api

I am using Python Google Sheets API v4 to create a new spreadsheet, insert some data and create 2 value doughnut chart based on the data within the spreadsheet.

I have managed to perform all of the above, but cannot figure out how to perform the following:

1. Apply predefined, rgb color values (there are only 2) in the request body build.
2. Ensure that charts are specific height and width size.

I have tried to pass the color parameters, however I keep receiving the following error about invalid JSON payload.

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "color" at 'requests[0].add_chart.chart.spec': Cannot find field.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'requests[0].add_chart.chart.spec', 'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "color" at \'requests[0].add_chart.chart.spec\': Cannot find field.'}]}]">
```

CODE:

```py
def create_pie_chart_body(range_list, sourceSheetId):
    #Creates pie chart body from the given range_list and worksheetId, pieHole: 0.75"
    return {
        "requests": [
            {
            "addChart": {
                "chart": {
                "spec": {
                    "title":str(range_list[-1]),
                    "pieChart": {
                    "domain": {
                        "sourceRange": {
                        "sources": [
                            {
                            "sheetId": sourceSheetId,
                            "startRowIndex": range_list[0],
                            "endRowIndex": range_list[1],
                            "startColumnIndex": range_list[2],
                            "endColumnIndex": range_list[3]
                            }
                        ]
                        }
                    },
                    "series": {
                        "sourceRange": {
                        "sources": [
                            {
                            "sheetId": sourceSheetId, 
                            "startRowIndex": range_list[4],
                            "endRowIndex": range_list[5],
                            "startColumnIndex": range_list[6], #last column
                            "endColumnIndex": range_list[7]
                            },
                        ],
                            "color":{
                                "red":0.94,
                                "green":0.87,
                                "blue":0
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    "pieHole":0.75},

                },
                "position": {
                    "overlayPosition":{
                        "anchorCell":{
                            "sheetId": sourceSheetId,
                            "rowIndex": 0,
                            "columnIndex":range_list[8]
                        },
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: `color` cannot be included in `series`. I think that the reason of your issue is this. So I cannot understand about your goal. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample data and sample output chart you want? By this, I would like to confirm about your issue.

Comment: @Tanaike if colors cannot be included in series, that means my goal 1 cannot be achieved. Are there any alternative methods that you could possible direct me to in order to create doughnut charts within the google sheet via API? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that when `color` from `series` of the request body is removed, a doughnut chart can be created. But from your question and replying,. I cannot image your goal So I'm not sure whether this is the result you want. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: To add to @Tanaike 's comments, I believe the right property you're looking for to change the color of the pieces of the pie chart is in `slices` ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options)), you can customize each slices' colors with this property.